# How can I use Javascript to play an MP3 stored on the clients machine using their installed media player?

Tags: javascript, shell, mp3

Say I have a path and filename pointing to an MP3 on a clients machine, and a path/filename pointing to their media player (eg Winamp or VLC).  How can I play the MP3 using their player?

Is there any kind of Shell() functionality in Javascript?  Googling for the likes of "javascript shell" provides results oriented towards an execution environment for js, not a system shell, and "javascript play mp3" (etc) finds instructions for inserting an `<audio>` element.  My googling skills are failing me...

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder)'s advice I have found a (possible) solution: creating a protocol handler.

This is the registry file I created:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\playmp3]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\playmp3]
@="URL:playmp3 Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\playmp3\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\playmp3\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\playmp3\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PlayMP3\\playmp3.bat %1"
```

If a user imports this into their registry, then entering `playmp3://E:\My Music\My Really Cool Song.mp3` into a browser address bar will trigger my batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET "url=%1"

SET "player=C:\Program Files (x86)\Winamp\winamp.exe"

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET url=!url:playmp3://=!
SET url=!url:/=!

"%player%" "%url%"

ENDLOCAL
```

...which strips the "playmp3://" (protocol) from the string and passes it to Winamp.exe :)

Doing this, I successfully created a link on a page that, when clicked, began playing a track in Winamp :)

Sure, it requires the user execute a registry script, specify a path to an executable in the batch file, then put it in a certain place... but it works! :)

Comment: Cool! Nice to see the full example.

Comment: Thanks :)  Is it wrong of me to switch the "correct" tick from your answer suggesting a solution to my answer showing the solution?  Wish I could give you credit as well... I wouldn't have been able to do this without your mention of creating a protocol handler.

Comment: @ Alex: Not a problem, it's totally fine to answer your own questions and it's fine to accept those answers. Your answer actually shows how to do it, whereas I just suggested doing it.

Answer (score 2):

As you've tagged your question `shell` I'm guessing you're talking about command-line JavaScript, **not** JavaScript running in a web browser. (If you're talking about JavaScript running in a web browser, the answer of course is: You can't do that, thank Goodness.)

For command-line JavaScript, how you do this depends on what JavaScript environment you're using, and the answer should be found in that environment's documentation. I know of at least these:

- NodeJS - You would use the [`process`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html) stuff to launch the player.
- JScript - You would use the [`WshShell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) object.
- SilkJS - You would use the [`builtin/process`](http://silkjs.net/documentation/builtin/process) stuff.
- Rhino - Rhino has access to the full Java JDK, so you would use one of the `exec` functions on [`Runtime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) or the [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) stuff.

...but there are lots of others.

---

Re your comment below:

> Unfortunately yeah, I'm talking about running in a browser...

You could *try* adding an [`audio` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-audio-element.html#the-audio-element) to the page with a `file://` URL corresponding to the MP3 file path, or even an `a` tag for older browsers, but that won't trigger the user's music player, it will just (at best) play the music in the browser. At worst it won't play anything because the file isn't from the same origin as your page (see the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), I haven't played with audio in this regard but surely there's an SOP issue here somewhere).

This is for the very, very good reason that JavaScript on web pages can't execute arbitrary programs on the client computer.

Comment: Unfortunately yeah, I'm talking about running in a browser... I thought this might be the answer I'd get, but wanted to try anyway.  Is there any workaround?  Even some way to prompt a "save/open" dialog or something?  Is there ANY web technology that would let me do this?  "In programming, ANYTHING is possible"  *cross fingers*

Comment: @AlexMcMillan: I've added an update, but you can't control how the file is played, and I wouldn't be at all sure it will get played at all.

Comment: Yes - JS executing stuff = bad, understood.  But there's got to be a way to do this.. maybe something other than JS?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan: That's a different question. :-) Yes, at the very least a signed Java applet can do this. Because they're signed, the user is asked whether to allow them to do things that are potentially harmful (and then the browser -- or maybe it's the plug-in -- remembers the choice). Flash and/or Silverlight may have similar functionality, but I don't know that for a fact. (And do try the `audio` or `a` tag with the `file://` URL, it may well work -- but just for playing the audio, not for launching their player.)

Comment: @AlexMcMillan: And of course, you can always implement a browser plug-in (a "protocol handler") that handles a particular protocol (perhaps, `mp3://`). Since the user has to *install* the plug-in, they are assumed to have given it rights to do potentially harmful things. So it all comes down to: Yes, it's *possible*, if you want to put in enough time, and the user is willing to trust you enough to at least say yes to the "danger! danger! Will Robinson!" warning from the browser, or possibly even download and install something.

Comment: Yeah I'd love to be able to (and will should all else fail) but I'm really being pushed for a way to do this "in Winamp".  Tried searching for any existing applets, but everything seems to assume I want to play it IN BROWSER.  Any advice that might help me find something?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan: Not beyond the above (a bit of comment overlap there). Good luck!